# Вывод даты mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести дату в `input type="date"` из бд mysql.
Так дата не выводится `<input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_birthday" value="<?php echo $row['date_birthday']; ?>">`

Comment: а что находится в `$row['date_birthday']`?

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov 0000-00-00

Comment: и это по вашему правильно? поле `type="date"` вроде не может принять такой вариант, он же не корректен

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov в этом и вопрос, как вывести дату....

Comment: Схема 100% рабочая: 1. Подключаемся к базе. 2.Выбираем БД. 3. Делаем запрос к нужной таблице, где есть поле с датой. 4. Производим выборку. 5. Выводим данные. 6. Закрываем соеденение

Comment: Раз у вас выходит `0000-00-00` то это шаг 4. Вы производите выборку даты в базе где нет этой даты, данные поставлены по умолчанию. Обновите свои данные

Comment: а как нам воспроизвести вашу проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто:

```
<input type="date" value="<?=datetime_format($row["date_birthday"],"d.m.Y")?>" />
```